# How to Install OxyPlot NuGet Package?

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

Good Day. I'm trying to Install an OxyPlot NuGet Package here in my Visual Studio 2015. However, I'm not successful in doing so. I'll use it in creating a Pie Chart in my Xamarin.Forms Portable Application.

First I've installed **OxyPlot.Core v1.0.0-unstable2100** , then **OxyPlot v1.0.0-unstable2100** , but when I tried to install the last one I need which is **OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms**, it prompt an error saying

> Unable to find a version of 'OxyPlot.Core' that is compatible with 'OxyPlot.WindowsForms 1.0.0-unstable2100 constraint: OxyPlot.Core (= 1.0.0-unstable2100)', 'OxyPlot.Wpf 1.0.0-unstable2100 constraint: OxyPlot.Core (= 1.0.0-unstable2100)', 'OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms 1.0.0-unstable1983 constraint: OxyPlot.Core (= 1.0.0-unstable1983)'.

What do you think is the reason behind this?

Is there an order to follow in Installing OxyPlot Packages? Which package do I need to install first?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to install anything in a certain order when it comes to [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/). Any kind of dependencies that are needed will get downloaded automatically. In other words, when you add the `OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms`-package to your project, the correction version of `OxyPlot.Core` will be added as well.

The [`OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/)-package can be found on the official nuget.org NuGet feed as well, but since it's a prerelease , make sure you have selected the **Include Prerelease** selection in the *Manage NuGet Packages* window of Visual Studio.

I've just tested it and it seems to work. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Please see: http://www.oxyplot.org/announcements/nuget-packages

To use these packages, you must add the myget feed https://www.myget.org/F/oxyplot as a package source.